# Creating 2 data frames from 2 different excel sheets.I want to pick Col1 from excel1 & Col2 from excel2.Store these cols in a New excel sheet

Tags: python, pandas

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndJG5.png)[Actual Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/538VX.png)[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIuBM.png)Firstly Both the columns are different with different data.
Gathering these   columns data from 2 different sheets and adding those collected columns in a new excel sheet. While writing to an excel sheet i can see BLANK cells.Below is the sample o/p i got.
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knWa7.png)
Please Find the attached snippet for reference (Actual & Expected Results)

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.read_csv(r'File1.dat', sep='|')
df1 = data1.loc[:, ['Sheet1_Col1']].drop_duplicates()


data2 = pd.read_excel(r'File2.xlsx')
df2= data2[data2['Sheet2_Col2'] == 'Number'].loc[:,'SOURCE_CODE'].drop_duplicates()

df_all_rows = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)

after_concat = df_all_rows.to_excel('New_Sheet.xlsx',  sheet_name='Collected_columns', index=False)
```

Expected Result is columns collected from 2 different excel sheets should be able to add these collected data in a new excel sheet

Comment: This would be simpler to answer if you provide a sample of your data so we can reproduce and test.

Comment: Please find the below sample data:                                                               Col1    Col2
Work 
E-Mail 
Personal 
Business 
              FAX
              MOBILE
              MOBILE_PHONE
              PHONE
              WORK
              Personal
              Business
              Mobile Phone
-NONE-

Comment: Better to add it in the question, so you can format it properly. Click the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56609583/edit) button. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) too.

Comment: Hi Valentino,I've attached a snippet for your reference. Actual Result, Expcted Result & Sample data (Table). Please provide your valuable feedback. I'm stuck now.